# Error in xy.coords Script vs Console

Tags: r

Simple code to plot two normal distributions:

```
a=-40
b=40
x <- seq(a, b, length=100)
hx <- dnorm(x,sd=1)
plot(x, hx, type="l", lty=2, xlab="x value",
     ylab="Density", main="Gaussian",col="blue")
hx <- dnorm(x,sd=2)
lines(x, hx, lwd=2, col="red")
lines()


legend("topright", 
       c("σ²=1","σ²=2"),     
       lty=c(1,1), 
       lwd=c(2.5,2.5),
       col=c("blue","red"),
       inset = .02
)
```

Why do I keep getting:
Error in xy.coords(x, y) : argument "x" is missing, with no default

If run from script, but works when run from console? How it's even possible that there could be a difference between running from sourcing script vs running from console? (I'm using Rstudio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by calling `lines` without arguments. If you run the code line by line you still get this error, but the other lines of code work without error and produce the expected output. If you source everything at once, execution is stopped by the error.

Comment: Good, next question is: if there's an error in the script, why doesn't Rstudio warns me?

Comment: On my mac, if I send everything to R at once with the "run lines" command, I see the output and there is the error message after the `lines()` line. If I use the "source" command I get only the error message.

Comment: weird. Do you recommend using run over source?

Comment: There is nothing weird here. It's expected (and I assume documented) behavior. I recommend using the workflow that suits you best and lets you catch all errors and warnings.